# How to match by character vector with slightly different strings

Tags: string, r, character, match

I am trying to add several columns to a data.frame from an other data.frame:

The data.frame from which I want to add columns:

```
 head(fix)[1:2,]
Year                                         Name Moders.hjälp. Utg.Sjukvård. Antal.Fall.Moderskapshjälp. Antal.Dagar.Moderskapshjälp. Antal.Dödsfall.
1 1921                                      Allians          2003            NA                          42                         1603              43
2 1921 Bageri- och konditoriindustriarb. I Stocholm            NA            NA                          NA                           NA              10
```

In other words, I want to add `fix[,3:ncol(fix)]` to the:

```
head(data)[1:4,]
    Year                                                 Name Delägare.män. Delägare.kvinnor. Sjukdomsfall.män.
92  1921                                         Sbk. Allians          2416              1610               526
198 1921 Bageri- och Konditoriindustriarb. I Stockholm sbh-k.           143                13                19
```

by matching the `Year` column and `Name` column.

The `problem`is that:

The column `Name` in `fix` and `data` above have slightly different names (i.e. `Allians` VS `Sbk. Allians`). I can't find a correct solution that matches parts of strings to find similarities. I tried to use `match` but didn't succeed...

Here is `dput`

`dput(head(fix)[1:2,])`

```
structure(list(Year = c(1921L, 1921L), Name = c("Allians", "Bageri- och konditoriindustriarb. I Stocholm"
), Moders.hjälp. = c(2003, NA), Utg.Sjukvård. = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), Antal.Fall.Moderskapshjälp. = c(42L, NA), Antal.Dagar.Moderskapshjälp. = c(1603L, 
NA), Antal.Dödsfall. = c(43L, 10L)), .Names = c("Year", "Name", 
"Moders.hjälp.", "Utg.Sjukvård.", "Antal.Fall.Moderskapshjälp.", 
"Antal.Dagar.Moderskapshjälp.", "Antal.Dödsfall."), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

`dput(head(data)[,c(1:2,11:13)])`

```
structure(list(Year = c(1921L, 1924L, 1921L, 1924L, 1921L, 1924L
), Name = c("Sbk. Allians", "Sbk. Allians", "Bageri- och Konditoriindustriarb. I Stockholm sbh-k.", 
"Bageri- och Konditoriindustriarb. I Stockholm sbh-k.", "Bergsunds verkstads arbetares sbk", 
"Bergsunds verkstads arbetares sbk"), Delägare.män. = c(2416L, 
3896L, 143L, 129L, 280L, 289L), Delägare.kvinnor. = c(1610L, 
4300L, 13L, 13L, 2L, NA), Sjukdomsfall.män. = c(526L, 1084L, 
19L, 34L, 100L, 97L)), .Names = c("Year", "Name", "Delägare.män.", 
"Delägare.kvinnor.", "Sjukdomsfall.män."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(92L, 
93L, 198L, 199L, 222L, 223L))
```

Greatful for any proposals!

Comment: Is the full name from `fix` always part of the name from `data`?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `agrep`. I'm still not clear on *what* you want to do though.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto `agrep` could be the answer.. But how could I put it in `match`?

Comment: @alexwhan I would like to partially match names from fix. Some part of the name is always in `data`

Comment: @user1665355, if you clarify what you're trying to do, I'd probably be able to make a suggestion. Which names are the correct ones? `fix` or `data`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am trying to add columns from `fix` to `data` by matching the `correct` names in `data` with the `not correct` names in `fix`. Second, the `Year` column value in `fix` must also match the `Year` column in `data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `agrep`:

```
sapply(data$Name, function(x) agrep(x, fix$Name, max.distance=0.4))
```

which matches data$Name with fix$Name. You could also play around with max.distance (perhabs in a loop). Afterwards you can merge/index/etc what you want with the matches...

**Update**

Something along these lines should do the job for you:

```
# match
matches <- sapply(data$Name, function(x) agrep(x, fix$Name, max.distance=0.4))
# clean match
matches_cleaned <- sapply(matches, function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 0,x, NA))
# add matched names to data
data$fix_names <- fix$Name[matches_cleaned]

# merge
merge(data, fix, by.x = c('Year', 'fix_names'), by.y = c('Year', 'Name'))
```

Comment: thanks! Any idea how I also can match the `Year` column at the same time? Because I have several years for the same company present in `data` and `fix`...

Comment: @user1665355, perhaps something along the lines of a combination of this solution and `merge` would help out.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am trying that right now but really can't do it correctly...:/ Still a beginner at R:) Could you write the code plz?:)

Comment: @EDi Thanks, trying to change the `max.distance` but still don't get the correct matches:/

Comment: Well, thats the tricky thing about this. Sometimes, like in your example `Bergsunds` has no match with fix.

Comment: @EDi yeah..Maybe `grep`` is better?

Comment: @EDi maybe this function I use could help? namezz=function(thepatternx,data,Name){
  
  library(stringr)
  
  thepattern=thepatternx
  
  pattern <- thepattern
  strings <- data$Name
  mja=str_detect(strings, pattern)
  yez= rownames(data[which(mja==TRUE),])
  hhh=as.numeric(yez)+1
  return(hhh)
  
  
  
}

namezz( "förgylleri" , data = data )

Comment: @user1665355: Have a look at http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2013/02/26/the-stringdist-package/

Comment: @user1665355: What is not working? I belief the code I have written above gives the correct result with your provided example data. It is your responsibility to support your question with the need information.

Comment: @EDi I found out that `agrep` does not match some names correctly. I tried to keep the question as small as possible. I accept your answer because it is very beatiful and I learned agrep a little bit:) Thanks!